# unable to configure reporting services web part viewer

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to display an SSRS report inside the sharepoint 2010 report viewer web part here is my configuratio
SSRS web service url servername:port/reports
my report path is: Folder/Report1

having entered this information in the web part's configuration all I see is a directory view of all folder
Sever/Reports -/
              Data Sources
              DataSets
              Folder

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying to configure with **`servername:port/ReportServer`** instead ?

These are the web services (/reportserver ... unless your SSRS is configured in an "exotic" way), the other (/server) is the web administration interface.